# Find prob. to see $5$ people in hairshop

Tags: calculus, probability, markov-chains

A hair shop, people arrives at the rate $1$ person/hour, and it spend $0.5$ hour to completely cut the hair. Find the probability to see $5$ peoples in the hair shop, including the person who are cutting?

Update: The ultilization $\rho=\frac{1}{2}$

The pro. has 5 people in hair shop is
$P[M=5]=\sum_{k=1}^{5}(1-\rho)\rho^k=0.484375$

Is it correct? I am not sure about the range of $k$ in the sum

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? As written, this problem is completely deterministic.

Comment: Yes. I will update it

Comment: $GNU Supporter: I updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The probability to see **exact** 5 people in the system is

$$P_5=\rho^5\cdot (1-\rho) $$.

The sigma sign is not needed here. Your are right that $\rho=\frac{\lambda}{\mu}=\frac{1}{2}$.